# Is it good way to work with database in model class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, model-view-controller

I am beginner at .Net Core and MongoDB. I am working on my own project, where are a few objects in **Models** layer, for example, User

```
Class User {

    [BsonElement("name")]
    string name;

    [BsonElement("email")]
    string email;

    // other fields...
}
```

The question is: **should I work with database inside the User model,**

```
Class User {

    [BsonElement("name")]
    string name;

    [BsonElement("email")]
    string email;

    // other fields...

    void saveToDatabase() {
        //some implementation to save object in database
    }
}
```

**or I should separate work with database and model of user?** Please, tell me best practice way to solve it.

Comment: ditch the layers maaaannn... learn vertical slices instead: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRns0rqPonA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i usually create a database class that handle working with database. i'll create an object of it and use it in other classes. i'm not sure that is the best way or not but maybe can be useful for you

the databse classes:

```
    public static class clsDB
{
    //-------------------< Class: DB >-------------------
    public static SqlConnection Get_DB_Connection()

    {
        //--------< db_Get_Connection() >--------
        //< db oeffnen >
        string cn_String = Properties.Settings.Default.connection_string;
        SqlConnection cn_connection = new SqlConnection(cn_String);

        if (cn_connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) cn_connection.Open();

        //</ db oeffnen >



        //< output >

        return cn_connection;

        //</ output >

        //--------</ db_Get_Connection() >--------

    }
    public static DataTable Get_DataTable(string SQL_Text)

    {
        //--------< db_Get_DataTable() >--------
        SqlConnection cn_connection = Get_DB_Connection();
        //< get Table >
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL_Text, cn_connection);
        adapter.Fill(table);
        return table;
    }

    public static void Execute_SQL(string SQL_Text)
    {
        //--------< Execute_SQL() >--------
        SqlConnection cn_connection = Get_DB_Connection();
        //< get Table >
        SqlCommand cmd_Command = new SqlCommand(SQL_Text, cn_connection);
        cmd_Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    public static void Close_DB_Connection()
    {
        //--------< Close_DB_Connection() >--------

        string cn_String = Properties.Settings.Default.connection_string;

        SqlConnection cn_connection = new SqlConnection(cn_String);

        if (cn_connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed) cn_connection.Close();

        //--------</ Close_DB_Connection() >--------
    }
}
```